# Do you have recordings for cycling - eg - tour de France

Tags: fx

Does anyone have FX/recordings of cycling races/crowds/bike pasts etc, (exterior not interior) that they would be willing to trade, or even sell?
I need a ton of stuff - am going to be recording lots, but need as much variety as possible. 
Particularly looking for mass of bikes past/ french/italian crowd at races. Individual bikes

If so please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

http://www.freesound.org/people/jakobthiesen/sounds/98184/

here you go sir, maybe this will help

Answer (score 2):

We have some nice Tour De France sounds in the BBC Library.  Audition/download them here:

http://download.prosoundeffects.com/#!explorer?s=tour%20de%20france